# IIS6 log file reporting chunks as completed downloads for pdf files when mapped to process all request through the asp.net engine

Tags: asp.net, iis, pdf, logging, iis-6

On a Windows 2003 SP2 server with IIS 6, we configured IIS to process all request through the ASP.NET engine using aspnet_isapi.dll
as outlined here  http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2007/07/27/Configure-IIS-for-Wildcard-Extensions-in-ASP.NET.aspx
After the change, we noticed a huge increase in hits for pdf files.

For example, before we made the change, a 7Mb file was "hit" 78 times in a day as indicated by an HTTP status of 200 . 
After the change, that same file reported 22,000 "hits" in a single day.

In looking at the logs, it seems that the http status of 200 is being returned on every chunk, instead of for a completed download.
This is an extract from the log file before the change

```
cs-method sc-status sc-substatus    sc-win32-status sc-bytes
GET       200   0       0       7452463     
HEAD      200   0       0       259         
GET       200   0       0       7452463     
HEAD      200   0       0       259
```

the first and second line represent a request from one ip address, the third and fourth are from a second IP address

and here is a similar extract from a log file created after we made the change

```
cs-method   sc-status  sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes
GET     200     0       0       7379092 
GET     200     0       0       102331  
GET     200     0       0       4249
GET     200     0       0       4212
GET     200     0       0       4521
GET     200     0       0       477
GET     200     0       0       4521
GET     200     0       64      196608
GET     200     0       0       6740403
```

The first request is from one IP Address, while the remaining lines are from a second IP address.

My question is this. Is there a way for me to cause the download of a pdf file to be recorded as a single hit, as it seemed to before I made the change?

Comment: I am not a expert on this but if they where chuncks I would expect a HTTP 200 with header Accept-Ranges: bytes, followed by HTTP 206 requests, requesting a byte range. To narrow it down I would do a diff on all the HTTP headers between the before and after scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the log is logging the actual requests, and it's the client's browser which decided to split it into chucks for more efficient downloading.

If the purpose of this project is for reporting, I would recommend creating a parser app/service to count PDF hits by IP address within a certain timeframe, rather than trying to hack the logging mechanism.